# Get decorated function object by string name

Tags: python, string, function, decorator

```
def log(func):
    def wraper(*a, **kw):   
        return func(*a, **kw)
    return wraper

@log
def f():
    print 'f'


print locals()['f'] # - prints <function wraper at 0x00CBF3F0>.
```

How do you get the real f object (not decorator wrap)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't.<sup>1</sup>  Store it if you need to access it later.

```
def log(func):
  def wrapper(*a, **kw):
    return func(*a, **kw)
  wrapper.func = func
  return wrapper

@log
def f():
  print 'f'

print f.func
```

<sup><sup>1</sup> You could mess with the closure, but I can't recommend it.</sup>

Answer (score 7):

The [functools](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html) module also provides a `wraps` decorator which makes sure that the wrapped function looks more like the real function: correct name, module, and docstring, for example.

Comment: +1 This should probably be the accepted answer as `functools.wraps` does more than just setting `wrapper.func = func`.

Comment: Actually, wraps doesn't seem to do precisely what the OP wanted: it doesn't preserve the original function somewhere.  But it may be that the OP didn't want the function, just needed an attribute off of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running python 3.2 or above, and you use [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) then you will find the wrapped function on the `__wrapped__` attribute:

```
from functools import wraps

def log(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*a, **kw):
        return func(*a, **kw)
    return wrapper

@log
def f():
    print 'f'

print f.__wrapped__
```

`functools.wraps`is a convenience function for decorating a decorated function with the function that does all the work, including adding this attribute [`functools.update_wrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.update_wrapper).